# Using ANSI C code block in a C# application

Tags: c#, c, c#-4.0

We have an application that runs on an embedded target using a LEON2 processor which is written in ANSI C.
We seem to have an issue with the code calculating the checksum and I'd like to simply copy that function into a C# application to test it.

I'd really like to be able to do something in those lines so I could really have the same code that is on the embedded target rather than rewriting it and potentially adding errors or doing it differently.

Is this possible?

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874603/is-it-possible-to-embed-c-code-in-a-c-project)

Comment: thanks sir, apparently what I want to do is not possible like this. I'd have to make a lib with my c function. I think I was thinking about the C++ blocks you can use extern "C" and confused it with C# :(

Comment: If you show us the code, there is the possibility that it can be copied in unsafe C# code. It depends on how you did it.

Answer (score 2):

**I'd like to simply copy that function into a C# application to test it.**

Unfortunately, you can't. C# is a managed language, unlike native C. C# is therefore not backward-compatible with C/C++, and you cannot mix unmanaged code in your C# application.

**I'd really like to be able to ... have the same code that is on the embedded target rather than rewriting it ...**

Create a separate DLL that exports the necessary function(s) and call them from there.