# Using C functions in C# Program

Tags: c#, c

I have several C functions that I would like to use in my C# application without having to change them as they already are.  Is there a SIMPLE way to use them without having to chop them up into a DLL or is that the only path forward?  Can I just link the direct path to where these files live and use them in my C# application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to embed C code in a C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874603/is-it-possible-to-embed-c-code-in-a-c-sharp-project)

Comment: C is a compiled language. You need to compile that code before you can execute it. Ideally, to a DLL, so that you can then call them through P/Invoke. But otherwise, no, a C# compiler cannot compile C code. The only other approach I can think of is to rewrite the C code into C#, or wrap it in a C++/CLI project.

Comment: If they're not in a .dll/.so, where are they?

Comment: @ikegami they are in their respective .c files located in a separate directory from the C# application

Comment: C is not a language that is interpreted at runtime. How do you expect this to work? Have the C files processed by a preprocessor with what flags?

Comment: Re "*they are in their respective .c files*", `.c` files contain source code, not executable code. You're asking how to execute functions, so you need them in their executable form. You will need to compile them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a bunch of C files lying around your project. They contain functions you want to call from C# code. Fair enough, sure, so let's count the possible ways you can achieve that.

1. Rewrite those functions into C#. This might actually be the most sensible option if those functions aren't being used elsewhere (like in a separate C project, for example), because then you don't have to maintain code in two separate languages for the same project. C# also has many advantages over C, like safety and expressiveness, and depending on what those functions are doing, you might not even see a significant performance difference.
2. Put that code in a native DLL, [export those functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll), and use P/Invoke from C# to call them. This is what involves the least modification to the original code.
3. Write a C++/CLI wrapper that calls those functions, and call the C++/CLI code from C#. This is especially useful if you want to present an OOP-style interface to the C# code.
4. Use [a C interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c) to execute those C files like they were scripts. This will probably be slower, more brittle, harder to maintain, and there might be other restrictions depending on which interpreter you use and what your C code looks like.